# How do I import a module as a type?

Tags: typescript

How can I refactor the following code so that I can simply import an object that implements a Typescript interface. I would like to get the following code down to a single line:

```
import configuration from './config';
let config: Configuration = configuration;
```

**config.ts**

```
const dev = {
    backend: {
        host: "https://localhost:5001"
    }
}

const prod = {
    backend: {
        host: undefined
    }
}

const config = process.env.REACT_APP_STAGE === 'production' ? prod : dev

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-anonymous-default-export
export default {
    ...config
}
```

**types.ts**

```
export interface Configuration {
    backend: BackendConfiguration
}

export interface BackendConfiguration {
    host?: string
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the dynamic import in a type expression to target a module's type:

```
let config: import('./config') = configuration;
```

I'm not entirely sure how it works with default imports though, you might have to add `.default` to it.